# Spider-Man's resilience inconsistency

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

I was looking through some questions on this SE and I came across the following one asked a couple of years ago:

[Spider-Man's resilience](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76415/spider-mans-resilience/76423#76423)

Now this all makes sense and I'm happy with the answer, however, it seems a bit inconsistent.

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home*,

> Spider-Man gets hit by a train and passes out entirely. Even when he wakes up, presumably a few hours later, in a prison cell in the Netherlands he is limping and and very scratched up.

I don't really understand how this is consistent with the two examples that OP posted:

- Being relatively unharmed after a concrete roof fall on his head
- Hanging on the outside of a crashing giant plane which explosion can be seen from the Avengers tower on the other side of NYC and leave with just a nose bleed

**Why does he take so much longer to recover/why is he so much more beaten up after this encounter compared to his very quick healing in other scenarios?**

Comment: Seems like a case of liberal use of [plot armor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor) when convenient.

Comment: Why inconsistency? The moving train would have killed any other human being in matter of seconds. He survived it for hours. If anything, they just focused on the bruises (no open wounds, as those were likely healed) to add another aspect to the character, as he said himself at some point he can feel pain, even when it's not killing him. That's at least how I see it.

Comment: I understand that any normal human would be killed, it just seemed to me like he has more injuries than similar events had caused him

Comment: It's simple (and yes inconsistent)...he's exactly injured enough as required by the plot. Hence "plot armor". The same tends to be true of his strength, he's as strong as the plot requires - "proportional strength" is essentially irrelevant.

Comment: @Paulie, sorry I should have made it clear that my response was to Shadow only. I have already given Luciano a +1 for his answer

Comment: Then this is essentially a duplicate of the existing linked Q&A since the answer is "Yes, it's inconsistent" and apparently that's OK with the film producers.

Comment: @paulie my question is the asking the opposite of the linked question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't really much of an inconsistency between the events.

#### The roof falls on him

Peter is clearly in pain, hurting and is struggling to free himself initially. When he finally frees himself he also looks to limp a bit. It is also unclear if he was unconscious for a bit or not but it seems like he might have been. This is the least worst event of the 3 and he still gets some pretty bad injuries but due to his resilience he can carry on.

#### The plane crash

Whilst quite bad it isn't exactly as bad as it first seems. Peter manages to hold on for quite a while which means the momentum from the crash would have been lowered by the time he falls off. He then bounces along the ground and whilst it would hurt a lot and give him some injuries it wouldn't be *that* bad respectively for someone like him. The injuries are worse here than the roof scene but not as bad as the train scene because comparatively whilst it looks worse it actually wasn't.

#### The train scene

Peter gets hit by the train and is dragged for quite a way before he gets onto the train and passes out. His injuries are the worst of the lot here but it seems he probably passes out from more than just his injuries. At this point he is also physically and mentally exhausted from the fight with Mysterio and is somewhat confused. His injuries are quite bad but again not as bad as they first seem.

Comment: “He then bounces along the ground” — which, let's not forget, is a sandy beach.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with the people who say it is inconsistent. Peter's injuries in far from home should be the worse by far.
Being hit by a moving train is INFINITELY worse than the roof collapse or plane crash. The reason why? Physics.

I am not going to go into the boring science details, mainly because this movie is after all science fiction. But think of it like this:

A moving train has way more mass, inertia, and therefore force, than either of the other 2. Some might argue the plane would have more, but remember Peter is on the plane and subsequently moving at the same speed of the plane. The force his mass and inertia create help to mitigate the force he would feel from the impact.

There are some other forces to consider with a moving object hitting a standing still object. But again,  boring science stuff.

The bottom line is, a moving 6,000 ton train is a horrible force hitting an object not exerting much force itself.